# How to convert raw byte[] into bitmap in camera App

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap, camera

This is the picture taking fuction

```
class Camera {
...

void capturePicture() {
    Camera.Size size = mParams.getPictureSize();
    int bitsPerPixel = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(mParams.getPictureFormat());
    int bufferSize = (int) Math.ceil(size.width * size.height * bitsPerPixel / 8d) ;
    Log.d(TAG, "Picture Size : " + size.width + "\t" + size.height);
    Log.d(TAG, "Picture format : " + mParams.getPictureFormat());
    Log.d(TAG, "Bits per Pixel = " + bitsPerPixel);
    Log.d(TAG, "Buffer Size = " + bufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1382400];
    addBuffer(buffer);
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = () -> mCameraCallbacks.onShutter();
    Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = (data, camera) -> {
        mCameraControllerCallbacks.onPicture(data);
        };
    mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, pictureCallback, null, null);
}

public interface CameraCallbacks {
    void onPicture(byte[] bytes);
}
```

The the picture size should be 3264 x 2448 however the bitsPerPixel returns -1 so I can't use it to calculate. It turn out the minimum buffer size is 1382400 I don't know why.

Here is the Activity receives the callback

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Camera.CameraCallbacks

    @Override
public void onPicture(byte[] bytes) {

    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    final int[] ints = new int[bytes.length / 4];
    buffer.asIntBuffer().put(ints);
    Log.d(TAG,"Creating Bitmap of Size : "+mCameraView.mPictureSize.width +" x "+mCameraView.mPictureSize.height);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ints, mCameraView.mPictureSize.width, mCameraView.mPictureSize.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, PicturePreviewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("bitmap", bmp);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SAVE_PICTURE_OR_NOT);

}
```

The code here is obviously wrong and I am having trouble rearrange these byte[] into ints[] the way bitmap accepts because I don't know the data structure inside these bytes.
Also BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray won't work because it can't read raw data.

Can anybody help me on this one?

Comment: 720 * 480 * 4 = 1382400. Don't see where you're calling [`setPictureFormat()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#setPictureFormat(int)) or `setPictureSize()`.

Comment: set PictureSize was set to 3264 x 2448 in other section of the code which isn't shown here and PictureFormat there is only one option that is" int JPEG = 0x100"

Comment: I believe if you've asked for JPEG then `decodeByteArray()` will, in fact, work on the "raw" bytes (because they will be compressed). You can examine how big the array is and make an inference about the format. And the same data will probably be delivered to the `jpeg` callback of `takePicture()`. To the best of my understanding, many devices do not support raw uncompressed bytes, b/c its too much data, so I think you have to work with .jpeg.

Comment: I think you are right.It is impossible to get an uncompressed image data from an android camera,which also means the second parameter in Camera.takePicture() doesn't have much use at all.All I can to is to move pictureCallback from the second parameter (raw callback)to the third parameter(jpeg call) the take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve uncompressed bitmap data from android camera, so the picture call back need to move from RawCallback to JpegCallback and use decodeByteArray() to obtain Bitmap.Also it is unreliable to pass Bitmap through Intent So the simplest way is to write to the receiving Activity directly.The Code became like this:

```
    @Override
public void onPicture(byte[] bytes) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, mJpeg.get().length,null);
        PicturePreviewActivity.mBitmap=new WeakReference<>(bitmap);
        Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, PicturePreviewActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SAVE_PICTURE_OR_NOT);
    }
}
```